# Install Sonicwall Global VPN Client without administrator credentials?

Tags: vpn, installation, connection, sonicwall

**Does anyone know if it's possible to connect to a Sonicwall VPN without the Sonicwall Global VPN client?**

I'm stuck away from work here in Liverpool due to heavy snow and **can't get administrator access** to any machine here, so I **can't install the usual Sonicwall Global VPN client** to connect to work!

I'm running **Windows 7 64 bit,** if anyone knows any way I could get connected with or without the official Sonicwall client, and **without administrator access,** I'd be very much in your debt! (e.g. is there a portable version available??) Thanks, Sam ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question title I would say is a pretty hearty 'no' - however...

> any way I could get connected with or without the official Sonicwall client

Yes!  Certainly this isn't limited to SonicWall, but [here's a link](http://www.sonicwall.com/us/products/510.html) to their browser-based VPN appliance.  I could've sworn someone was pitching a separate license/service we could purchase for our existing firewall, but I may have misunderstood - I'm not finding a link.  However, that would get around your non-admin access to the computers within reach.

You will **not** be able to install the VPN client through any clever tricks. The VPN adapter functions to windows similarly to a hardware network adapter - that is to say, you need permissions such that you'd be able to add "hardware" to the system.  Blocking non-admins from this kind of access is a central part of the distinction between admin and user access.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use this method currently, as it looks like our company would need to set up SSL VPN, which they have not as yet. I'll have to request they add this feature for future use! Thanks for your answer though, I can't up-vote as I only have 1 reputation!

Comment: No worries, good luck and stay warm in Liverpool... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so very old questions however this seems like a 'work around' untested

Portable-VirtualBox, 
Tiny Linux Distro,
VPN instolled on virtual machine,
RDP to Windows client/server?

Untested option but something that has possibilities..